# how to load multiple urls in driver.get()?

Tags: python, selenium

How to load multiple urls in `driver.get()` ?

I am trying to load 3 urls in below code, but how to load the other 2 urls?

And afterwards the next challenge is to pass authentication for all the urls as well which is same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Users/RYadav/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Python 3.8/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://fleet.my.salesforce.com/reportbuilder/reportType.apexp")#put here the adress of your page

elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ext-gen63"]')#put here the content you have put in Notepad, ie the XPath

button = driver.find_element_by_id('id="ext-gen63"')

print(elem.get_attribute("class"))

driver.close

submit_button.click()
```

Comment: you want to amend existing url or its completely new url's?

Comment: other 2 are whole new urls

Comment: I would suggest you can create function which will accept url as an parameter

Comment: Totally new to Selenium aspect so have to bug in so much. I want to ask for every URL, the other parameter to take its XPath value in the function!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
def getUrls(targeturl):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" path for chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("http://www."+targeturl+".com")
    # perform your taks here
    driver.quit()

for i in range(3):
    webPage = ['google','facebook','gmail']
    for i in webPage:
        print i;
        getUrls(i)
```

Comment: this code works.Instead of opening whole new browser , can we fix it to open new tab for each url in same opened browser. I tried keeping driver.quit outside of the loop at the end. this does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load more than 1 url at a time for each Webdriver. If you want to do so, you maybe need some multiprocessing module. If you want to do an iterative solution, just create a list with every url you need and loop through it. With that you won't have the credential problem neither.

Comment: Sure, I will give a try using this way, Thank you.